# Intellij IDEA create new class from undefined import

Tags: intellij-idea

Suppose I have a java file that has an import that currently is not referencing any real class, because I plan on defining it myself. Is there an easy way to have intellij create a stub class for me in my module by making the file in the right folder based on the package name? I know I can just manually do this but I'm looking for something a bit more automatic, like if I could just right click the import and say "Create class stub".

Comment: Alt+Insert or Control+N on the Project Structure tab should do it...

Comment: ctrl-n opens a class on my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wait until it shows up as an error, you can <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> on the error to bring up idea's intentions, one of which should be an option to create the new class. You can also get the intentions by clicking the red lightbulb that appears next to the error when the cursor is on it. You should change your settings so that `F2 Goes to Errors First`, then you can press <kbd>F2</kbd> and the cursor will jump to the error making invoking the intentions a little faster.

Answer (score -2):

First thing `import that currently is not referencing any real class` it dont work like this in `intelliJ`. you cannot have an import statement for a non-existing thing. Suppose you have a package named `mypackage`. Then you can write something like -

```
import mypackage.*;
```

you can define a `className` inside the existing `class` then it will report you an error like the name appears to be RED just keep the cursor there Press `alt+ins` a menu pops up then select `create class` and then specify the package in `Destination package` field. In that way it will work.

Comment: Not on my mac it doesn't

Comment: I provided full description check it out